# Data File handling in classic c++ (much like C)

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I made the following program. There is a mistake in bold part. The value of count in the output I'm getting is zero. There were no errors when I compiled the code.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    void count();
    fstream file("STORY.TXT",ios::in|ios::out);
    file<<"He is playing in the ground. She\nis playinbg with her dolls.\n";
    file.close();
    count();
    getch();
}
void count()
{
    ifstream file("STORY.TXT");
    file.seekg(0);int count=0;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        char line[10];
        **file.get(line,10,' ');
        cout<<line<<"\n";
        if(line=="HE")
            ++count;**
    }
    cout<<count;
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Your `eof()` while loop could be wrong, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 3):

String comparison is not done through `==`. That merely compares the address
Replace

```
if(line=="HE")
```

with

```
if(!strcmp(line, "HE"))
```

**EDIT**

For case insensitive

```
if(!strcmpi(line, "HE"))
```

Comment: Its also case sensitive. So you will still get 0 for the count.

Comment: You want `strcasecmp` for case insensitive comparison.

Comment: oh yea..case sensitive.should i use getline or get function to obtain the string. Is it that get function retain the ' ' character and getline drop it??

Comment: Actually, in this century we do use `==` for std::string comparison. The reason it doesn't work is that the code and compiler are from a previous century.